# Dynamic sum column based on other selected columns from a dropdown or slicer in python dash

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly-dash

Hi guys if anyone could help here it would be great.

I have code (below) that sets up a dash app returning 4 plotly tables.
I have a 'Sum' column that is currently summing the next 9 column values in each table as new data gets added. Note this data is in reverse.

What I would like to do is actually have a dropdown up the top of the page where I can choose the columns that feed into the Sum column dynamically. Sometimes I might want to sum 3 columns, others 12 columns etc.
I would like this dropdown to be linked to all 4 tables.

Below is the code and a picture of what it currently looks like

```
from dash import Dash, dash_table
from dash import Dash, html
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import base64
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State
import io
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df1 = Backs_CON
df2 = Edges_CON
df3 = Middles_CON
df4 = HH_CON

app = Dash(__name__)

###### Colour 1  ###########

def data_bars(df, column):
    if (df[column] == 0).all():
        return []
    # function code here
    n_bins = 100
    bounds = [i * (1.0 / n_bins) for i in range(n_bins + 1)]
    min_value = 0
    max_value = df[column].max()
    ranges = [
        ((max_value - min_value) * i) + min_value
        for i in bounds
    ]
    styles = []
    for i in range(1, len(bounds)):
        min_bound = ranges[i - 1]
        max_bound = ranges[i]
        max_bound_percentage = bounds[i] * 100
        styles.append({
            'if': {
                'filter_query': (
                    '{{{column}}} >= {min_bound}' +
                    (' && {{{column}}} < {max_bound}' if (
                        i < len(bounds) - 1) else '')
                ).format(column=column, min_bound=min_bound, max_bound=max_bound),
                'column_id': column
            },
            'background': (
                """
                    linear-gradient(90deg,
                    #2ca02c 0%,
                    #2ca02c {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white 100%)
                """.format(max_bound_percentage=max_bound_percentage)
            ),
            'paddingBottom': 2,
            'paddingTop': 2
        })

    return styles

###### Colour 2  ###########

def data_bars1(df, column):
    if (df[column] == 0).all():
        return []
    # function code here
    n_bins = 100
    bounds = [i * (1.0 / n_bins) for i in range(n_bins + 1)]
    min_value = 0
    max_value = df[column].max()
    ranges = [
        ((max_value - min_value) * i) + min_value
        for i in bounds
    ]
    styles = []
    for i in range(1, len(bounds)):
        min_bound = ranges[i - 1]
        max_bound = ranges[i]
        max_bound_percentage = bounds[i] * 100
        styles.append({
            'if': {
                'filter_query': (
                    '{{{column}}} >= {min_bound}' +
                    (' && {{{column}}} < {max_bound}' if (
                        i < len(bounds) - 1) else '')
                ).format(column=column, min_bound=min_bound, max_bound=max_bound),
                'column_id': column
            },
            'background': (
                """
                    linear-gradient(90deg,
                    #d62728 0%,
                    #d62728 {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white 100%)
                """.format(max_bound_percentage=max_bound_percentage)
            ),
            'paddingBottom': 2,
            'paddingTop': 2
        })

    return styles

###### Colour 3  ###########


def data_bars2(df, column):
    if (df[column] == 0).all():
        return []
    # function code here
    n_bins = 100
    bounds = [i * (1.0 / n_bins) for i in range(n_bins + 1)]
    min_value = 0
    max_value = df[column].max()
    ranges = [
        ((max_value - min_value) * i) + min_value
        for i in bounds
    ]
    styles = []
    for i in range(1, len(bounds)):
        min_bound = ranges[i - 1]
        max_bound = ranges[i]
        max_bound_percentage = bounds[i] * 100
        styles.append({
            'if': {
                'filter_query': (
                    '{{{column}}} >= {min_bound}' +
                    (' && {{{column}}} < {max_bound}' if (
                        i < len(bounds) - 1) else '')
                ).format(column=column, min_bound=min_bound, max_bound=max_bound),
                'column_id': column
            },
            'background': (
                """
                    linear-gradient(90deg,
                    #bcbd22 0%,
                    #bcbd22 {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white 100%)
                """.format(max_bound_percentage=max_bound_percentage)
            ),
            'paddingBottom': 2,
            'paddingTop': 2
        })

    return styles

###### Colour 4  ###########
def data_bars3(df, column):
    if (df[column] == 0).all():
        return []
    # function code here
    n_bins = 100
    bounds = [i * (1.0 / n_bins) for i in range(n_bins + 1)]
    min_value = 0
    max_value = df[column].max()
    ranges = [
        ((max_value - min_value) * i) + min_value
        for i in bounds
    ]
    styles = []
    for i in range(1, len(bounds)):
        min_bound = ranges[i - 1]
        max_bound = ranges[i]
        max_bound_percentage = bounds[i] * 100
        styles.append({
            'if': {
                'filter_query': (
                    '{{{column}}} >= {min_bound}' +
                    (' && {{{column}}} < {max_bound}' if (
                        i < len(bounds) - 1) else '')
                ).format(column=column, min_bound=min_bound, max_bound=max_bound),
                'column_id': column
            },
            'background': (
                """
                    linear-gradient(90deg,
                    #9A5563 0%,
                    #9A5563 {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white 100%)
                """.format(max_bound_percentage=max_bound_percentage)
            ),
            'paddingBottom': 2,
            'paddingTop': 2
        })

    return styles

def generate_table(dataframe):
    columns = [{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in dataframe.columns]
    style_data_conditional = []
    for col in columns:
        if 'Min' in col['name']:
            style_data_conditional += data_bars(dataframe, col['id'])
        
        if 'Game' in col['name']:     
            style_data_conditional += data_bars1(dataframe, col['id'])
            
        if 'Con' in col['name']:    
            style_data_conditional += data_bars2(dataframe, col['id'])
            
        if col['name'] in ['Sum']:
            style_data_conditional += data_bars3(dataframe, col['id'])
            
    return dash_table.DataTable(
        data=dataframe.to_dict('records'),
        sort_action='native',
        columns=columns,
        style_table={'width': '95%',
            'overflowX': 'scroll',
            'scrollRight': '100%',
            'margin': '10px 0',
            'margin-left':'30px',
            'border': 'thin lightgrey solid',
            'maxHeight': '600px'},
        style_data_conditional=style_data_conditional,
        style_cell={
            'width': '50px',
            'text-align': 'center',
            'minWidth': '100px',
            'maxWidth': '180px',
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
            
        },
        style_cell_conditional=[
            {'if': {'column_id': 'Name'},
                'position': 'sticky',
                'left': '0px',
                'borderRight': 'thin lightgrey solid',
                'zIndex': '999',
            },
             {'if': {'column_id': 'Sum'},
                'position': 'sticky',
                'left': '99px',
                'borderRight': 'thin lightgrey solid',
                'zIndex': '999',
            }],
        style_header={
            'backgroundColor': 'maroon',
            'fontWeight': 'bold',
            'color': 'white',
        },
        page_size=40
    
    )

table1 = generate_table(df1)
table2 = generate_table(df2)
table3 = generate_table(df3)
table4 = generate_table(df4)

app.layout = html.Div(
    style={
        'text-align': 'center'},
    children=[
    html.H1(children='Longitudinal Conditioning Minutes'),
    html.Img(src='/assets/download.png',style={'height': '100px', 'width': '100px'}),
    html.H2(children='Backs'),
    table1,

    html.H2(children='Edges'),
    table2,
        
    html.H2(children='Middles'),
    table3,
        
    html.H2(children='HH'),
    table4,    
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!